# React-Native-Maps showsUserLocation={true} is behaving weird, the button is not always displayed

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps ([Link](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps)) and did showsUserLocation = {true} in MapView (Android). But the button is not being shown when the map loads for the first time.

Surprisingly, when I rotate my phone once, the button appears. Even I observed that if I lock the phone and unlock, the button appears. This made me think that the map might need a reload in order to make that button appear.

I observed the same thing when I have created a custom marker with an image. The marker appears after lock/unlock OR rotate/unrotate. Even more surprisingly, the click event works even if the marker is invisible.

Help me out guys!

Comment: this is because the map is not locating an address, the button will appear when onRegionChange is triggered, or the region prop is changed

Comment: Can't agree. I tried panning through the map which should essentially 
invoke onRegionChange(), but that does not make the button visible. :(

Comment: @TamalSen same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Nope. Waiting for an airbnb guy to reply.